# I need help finding all strings not included in (a*b)*

Tags: regex, programming-languages, computer-science, theory, kleene-star

I'm doing this for homework. I need to write a regular expression for a language over (`a`, `b`) that includes all strings not included in a language `(a*b)*`

for example 'aaaaaaabaaaaaaaabaaaaaaabaaaabaaaaaaaaab' would work. So I'm looking for a regular expression for allll the strings which are not included in that.

Can you help me at least get on the right step to figure it out?

I know that `a*b` means as many `a`'s as we want followed by one `b`. Then that whole sort as many times as we want.

Comment: @hwnd , Just need a way to reg expression which includes All strings not in ( (a as many times followed by b) as many times ).

Comment: You're not just talking `a*b*` are you? Or do you want to match aaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaabaaaaaab?

Comment: @r3mus, no no, I'm talking about '(a*b)*', so like what you have 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaab'. Then a regular expression in all strings which are not included in that.

Comment: OK, best reword your question to explain that more clearly - describe what you want to match or not match and provide some examples.

Comment: Still need more info. Provide several examples in a list of what you want to match, what you don't want to match, and what (if anything) you want to capture/remove from each.

Comment: @r3mus - The question is quite clear - provide a regex for a string over the alphabet ab that does match those strings that are not matched by (a*b)*

Comment: o_O ok then. Glad you sorted it out!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your `(a*b)*` regular expression matches anything that ends in a ***b*** or is empty.

so a regular expression that matches anything that end in ***a*** seems to be the solution..

`a$` or `/a$/`

Comment: @gaby aka G. Petrioli Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
[^ab]*
```

This probably should do the trick.
This says the string should not have any a or b. ^ is the symbol for negation.

Comment: Except OP wants everything *except* that.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the String and check for characters besides 'a' and 'b'. It seems chains of 'b's are allowed and the empty string are a part of the language, since the Kleene star allows for zero instances of the character.